# MVCC for concurrent user access and updates to document

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase, nosql

I have been having a read of MVCC within Couchbase db.

I have come to a point where I need to implement but am confused in regards to whether I should be using CAS or not to do the job?

Basically there could be a few users accessing the documents within couchbase and may need to update around the same time hence I believe I need to implement the versioning but just need pointing in the right direction.

Any help/advice would be great.

Regards

TJ

Comment: I think my answer to your other question linked below should answer this one too.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694291/how-to-get-the-revision-number-of-couchbase-document

Comment: As far as Im aware, Couchbase provides optimistic concurrency control : http://blog.couchbase.com/optimistic-or-pessimistic-locking-which-one-should-you-pick Check it out